How to setup a reverse proxy across multiple devices on a local network
I am very new to setting up servers and network management so please bear with me.
I have multiple devices on which I would like to self host different services. This includes a few RPI5 and another desktop server. I am trying to set it all up to host things like Pihole, Actual budget, game servers, etc. all across these devices.
I also have a domain that I would like to configure to be able to access these services via subdomains.
I have found a lot of resources on setting up a reverse proxy in order to direct traffic to specific services via subdomains, but from what I could gather, this is all running on the same physical device. I want to be able to have Pihole and Actual budget (and maybe other stuff down the line) running on Pi-1, some websites on Pi-2, and other random future projects on Pi-3. I want the desktop server to my game servers. And then, I want to be able to access these things from subdomains like actual.example.com or minecraft.example.com, etc.
I am not sure which device to put the reverse proxy on, or if each device actually needs its own reverse proxy, or how at all to configure all of this to work on the network.

You can use traefik with docker:
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=YOU_MAIL_HERE"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik/dynamic"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080" #Dashboard (optional)
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./dynamic_conf.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/dynamic_conf.yml" #conf file
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt" # Certs folder

I try to use dynamic conf buts it doesn't work, I have to restart the docker evrytime I add data in dynamic_conf.yml
dynamic_conf.yml
http:
  routers:
    minecraft:
      entryPoints:
      - websecure
      rule: Host(`minecraft.exemple.com`)
      service: minecraft
      tls:
        certResolver: myresolver
    
  services:
    minecraft:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - url: http://192.168.1.2:25565

On your DNS dashboard, make sure "minecraft.example.com" redirects to the server hosting Traefik. I recommend using "A" and "CNAME" records. Create an A record pointing to your public IP with "box.example.com" as the entry point, for example, then create a CNAME record for "minecraft.example.com" redirecting to "box". This way, if you have many entries pointing to your public IP, and if it changes, you only need to update the "A" record for "box" instead of changing every individual entry.


I have found a lot of resources on setting up a reverse proxy in order to direct traffic to specific services via subdomains, but from what I could gather, this is all running on the same physical device.

No, it really isn't specific to running on the same physical device, indeed many people specifically use a reverse proxy because they have more than one device. The proxy itself is a single instance because you only have one IP address and can only NAT ports 80/443 to a single device, but it's literally the job of the proxy to distribute requests to multiple internal devices.
You usually configure the proxy by giving it a URL of the backend to proxy to, and while the URL can point to http://localhost:1234 it can just as well point to http://192.168.1.7 across the LAN.

I am not sure which device to put the reverse proxy on

Whichever has a decent CPU and good network connection. It should have wired Ethernet (not WiFi), and it should be a PCI-based Ethernet interface or at least USB3, not the kind that old Pi's used to have.

or if each device actually needs its own reverse proxy

Technically not. When you have only a single public IP address, the whole purpose of the reverse proxy is that it distributes traffic, from that single entry point to multiple servers.
If the devices run many containers or services in general, they could benefit from having their own tier of proxies, but it's more a case by case thing than a strict need or not.

Thank you for the detailed answer. I will have to look into configuring the proxy. Do you have any experience/advice on what service to use to do this? Have read about both nginx and caddy and I am (hopefully) trying to do it in a docker container.

Traefik seems to be popular with Docker, as in J-Diablo's example. I haven't used it myself – so far Apache2 suits my needs.
